# Bulk insert into EAV tables example

Tags: php, mysql, insert, bulkinsert, entity-attribute-value

Please help me insert data into this EAV implementation.

I am fully aware of the drawbacks that an EAV table has, of the performance drawbacks and simply harder to maintain sql queries, but the current system already uses it and changing it is not an option.

The system uses the EAV tables to store temporary metadata that comes from various sources which "fill in" the attributes and values for the entities, and when the entity is complete it gets exported into proper tables.

I would love to use a NoSQL db for this, but as I already mentioned, changing the existing system is not an option :(

But what I am actually asking about is if there are any example of how to property insert into an EAV table, I can not find any on the web (all I see are articles of how evil EAV is, or that EAV is not evil if used properly or articles about Magento).

I am going to give a simplified example that you can copy & paste of how I am attempting to insert into these tables.

Note: the data is mostly the same strings over and over but in many different combinations for every "entity", it also uses php to do the actual inserting

Note 2: The problem becomes interesting because the flood of information to be saved is usually pretty large and the insert has to be efficient.

### Ready code to copy:

```
<?php
try {
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '000000';
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit('Failed to open database: '.$e->getMessage() );
}

#the entity
$dbh->exec('
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_entity` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(100),
`created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
');

#the value "type" or attribute
$dbh->exec('
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_attribute` (
`attr_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE,
`type` TINYINT(3),
PRIMARY KEY(`attr_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
');

#the table that holds the values, there is a "mostly" limited set of values and storing each one again and again makes no sense.
$dbh->exec('
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_value` (
`val_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`value` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY(`val_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
');

#the table that holds the references of the values and their attributes
$dbh->exec('
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_ref` (
`ent_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`attr_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`val_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`ent_id`,`attr_id`,`val_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
');

$input_rows = array(
    array(
        'item'=>'Item 1',
        'attr'=>'title',
        'val'=>'Item 1 title',
    ),
    array(
        'item'=>'Item 1',
        'attr'=>'code',
        'val'=>'983474',
    ),
    array(
        'item'=>'Item 1',
        'attr'=>'tag',
        'val'=>'Tag A',
    ),
    array(
        'item'=>'Item 1',
        'attr'=>'tag',
        'val'=>'Tag B',
    ),
    array(
        'item'=>'Item 2',
        'attr'=>'tag',
        'val'=>'Tag B',
    ),
    //... and so forth
);

//Build queries for values and attributes
$attr_values = array();
$attr_params = array();
$val_values = array();
$val_params = array();
foreach($input_rows as $row){
    $attr_values[] = '?';
    $attr_params[] = $row['attr'];
    $val_values[] = '?';
    $val_params[] = $row['val'];
}

//Insert the attributes and values, many might already exist in the db
if(!empty($attr_values)){
    $sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO `tbl_attribute` (`name`) VALUES ('.implode('),(',$attr_values).')';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($attr_params);
}
if(!empty($val_values)){
    $sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO `tbl_value` (`value`) VALUES ('.implode('),(',$val_values).')';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($val_params);
}

//Select the ID's of the values and attributes
$attr_ids = array();
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `attr_id`,`name` FROM `tbl_attribute` WHERE `name` IN('.implode(',',$attr_values).')');
$stmt->execute($attr_params);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $attr_ids[$row['name']] = $row['attr_id'];
}
$val_ids = array();
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `val_id`,`value` FROM `tbl_value` WHERE `value` IN('.implode(',',$val_values).')');
$stmt->execute($val_params);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $val_ids[$row['value']] = $row['val_id'];
}

//Insert the entities and references
$dbh->beginTransaction();
foreach($input_rows as $row){
    //One of my gripes with this approach is that I have to "replace into" instead of "insert into" so that the lastInsertId returns an id even if there is some constraint
    $sql = 'REPLACE INTO `tbl_entity` (`name`) VALUES (?)';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($row['item']));
    $id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    $sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO `tbl_ref` (`ent_id`,`attr_id`,`val_id`) VALUES (?,?,?)';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $val_id = $val_ids[$row['val']];
    $attr_id = $attr_ids[$row['attr']];
    $stmt->execute(array($id,$attr_id,$val_id));
}
$dbh->commit();

//Select data (selecting all columns only for this example)
$data = array();
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `id`,`name`,`created` FROM `tbl_entity`');
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $data[$row['id']] = $row;
}
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('
SELECT 
x.`ent_id` AS `item_id`,
a.`name` AS `attr`,
v.`value` AS `val`
FROM `tbl_ref` x
INNER JOIN `tbl_attribute` a USING(`attr_id`)
INNER JOIN `tbl_value` v USING(`val_id`)
');
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $data[$row['item_id']]['meta'][$row['attr']][] = $row['val'];
}
echo '<plaintext>';
print_r($data);
```

If you see any other issues please mention them if possible.
I am also happy to hear your opinion on how to solve this properly, even if I am not able to implement it right now it might be useful later for me or someone else.

P.S. I am not sure if this fits more on code review branch of stackexchange or stackoverflow, I am 50%/50% right now so posting here because there are more people, if I am wrong then how do I move/migrate this question?

P.P.S. I spent many hours researching this and 3 hours just writing this question, please answer!

Comment: A short, high-level description of your algorithm would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Normally (cough), an EAV table usually looks more like this.

```
create table eav (
  entity varchar(100) not null,
  attribute varchar(100) not null,
  value varchar(255) not null,
  primary key (entity, attribute, value)
);
```

This kind of structure lends itself to simple and efficient use of [MySQL's bulk loader](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html). I'd expect the input to be a CSV file.

```
"Item 1", "title", "Item 1 title"
"Item 1", "code", "983474"
"Item 1", "tag", "Tag A"
"Item 1", "tag", "Tag B"
"Item 2", "tag", "Tag B"
```

But inserting data using SQL statements is equally simple.

```
insert into eav values ('Item 1', 'title', 'Item 1 title');
insert into eav values ('Item 1', 'code', '983474');
...
```

If you're going to use surrogate ID numbers for all those values, your job is a lot harder and a lot less efficient. You have just a couple of options.

- Transpose the values to ID numbers before importing it.
- Import it into a staging table, determine the id numbers, then insert the data.